# Can't delete local git branch

Tags: git, version-control

So, I was deleting a local branch with the command git branch -D  and after deleting the branch, a new branch, named '-D' showed up in my local repo.  So now when I run 'git branch' there is a branch called '-D'.

Unfortunately, when I try to delete this branch, using 'git branch -D -D', I get a 'fatal: branch name required' error.

Any ideas how to get rid of this branch?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this and the command prompt returns that `-D` is an invalid branch name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
git branch -D -- -D
```

Where `--` is a fairly common syntax for "stop interpreting `-` as introducing an option after this point".  This seems to work in my test:

```
$ git branch
  -D
  foo
* master
$ git branch -D -- -D
Deleted branch -D (was 460317a).
```

If that doesn't work, you could try to delete `.git/refs/heads/-D` if it exists.